# Flash/AIR AS3: comparing contents of Screen.screens

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, screen, desktop-application

In a sane world, this works as expected:

```
var array:Array = ['a','b','c'];
trace(array.indexOf(array[0])); // returns 0
```

In an insane world, this happens:

```
trace(Screen.screens.indexOf(Screen.screens[0])); // returns -1
```

... if `Screen.screens` is an `Array` of the available instances of `Screen`, why can't that array give an accurate `indexOf` one of its own children?

**edit -**  To take it a step further, check this out:

```
for each(var i:Screen in Screen.screens){
 for each(var j:Screen in Screen.getScreensForRectangle(this.stage.nativeWindow.bounds)){
  trace(i, j, i == j); // returns false
  trace(i.bounds, j.bounds, i.bounds == j.bounds); // returns false
 }
}
```

At least one `Screen` listed in `Screen.screens` should be identical to a `Screen` in `Screen.getScreensForRectangle(this.stage.nativeWindow.bounds)` - but even if you compare the `Screen.bounds`, it still doesn't match up, despite the two `Rectangle` objects having the same dimensions!

Insanity, ladies and gentlemen! You don't even want to see the workaround I put together (hint: it involves comparing the values of `Screen.bounds.toString()` for the contents of `Screen.screens`)

Comment: I know, "screen, screen, screen dot screen dot screens." But I wanted to give a real example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an educated(?) guess, but since `Screen.screens` is read only, and modifying the array it returns has no effect, I think it's a fairly safe bet that internally, every time you call it Flash generates and returns a new array of `Screen` objects (rather than keeping an internal set of `Screen` objects and giving you access to them). When you call:

```
Screen.screens.indexOf(Screen.screens[0])
```

you make two separate accesses to `Screen.screens`, so if each of those calls is returning a different array of objects, it's easy to see why you don't find any matches - because the `indexOf` method tests for === equality, so two different `Screen` objects won't match, even if they happen to contain information about the same physical screen.

The solution is to grab a copy of the screens array and use it. This works fine:

```
var scr:Array = Screen.screens;
trace( scr.indexOf(scr[0]) ); // returns 0
```

Comment: Nice - I bet you're totally right, that's what's going on. Does that follow some sort of standard practice, I wonder? Because while the read-only array part makes sense, I'd expect it to be an array that was updated behind the scenes whenever the screens were changed around, instead of re-building the array every time it was requested... anyway, thanks, that's just what I wanted.

Comment: I think it's something generally to be wary of when testing objects for equality... whether an API gives you a reference to the same object as last time, or a new object, is ultimately a detail of the API's implementation that it's always safest not to have a dependency on. 

After all, you don't *really* care whether you have two references to the same object, what you care about is whether they refer to the same physical screen... which is kind of hard to determine in this case, but semantically you see what I mean. ;)

Comment: But to answer your question, generally I'd guess that something like Screen, which is just a lump of informational properties, is likely to be a throwaway object. Something like NativeApplication.openedWindows, which gives you very complex NativeWindow objects, might be more likely to give references to a persistent object. And after a quick test, it looks like it does. But better not to rely on it if you can avoid it, of course..